# Regex test() returns true but false is expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check if my regex is true. So this is what I have tried:

```
const a = new RegExp(`(?<=TITLE.+prefix=)[^\]|\|]+`);
```

That returns true, which is correct:

```
console.log(a.test('[TITLE|prefix=bss|suffix=a] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]'));
```

That one returns true but it shouldn't:

```
console.log(a.test('[ANYTHING|somethingelse=bss|suffix=a] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]'));
```

See here the result:

```js
const a = new RegExp(`(?<=TITLE.+prefix=)[^\]|\|]+`);
console.log(a.test('[TITLE|prefix=bss|suffix=a] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]'));
console.log(a.test('[ANYTHING|somethingelse=bss|suffix=a] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]'));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you create your REGEX with the constructor, i.e. as a string, you need to double-escape backslashes, so:

```
new RegExp(`(?<=TITLE.+prefix=)[^\\]|\\|]+`)
```

Also note that `|\|` is unnecessary; should be just `|`. Inside a range, the pipe character does not have special relevance so it will be matched literally.

Comment: Why do you (a user who should know the rules) add an answer to a duplicate (which has already been closed as such)?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I concede the point. I normally never do this; I'm not really sure why this one didn't immediately strike me as having a likely duplicate. Speaking of rules, you will know, though, that this is not, in itself, grounds for downvoting. Voting should pertain only to the quality of the answer.